# How do I format Datetime to remove seconds in model?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, datetime, formatting

I'm using Datetime and would like seconds removed from what is stored in my database. In one of my old projects, I formatted the date part of Datetime like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

But how would I go about formatting the whole thing, date and time? Currently, input is being stored in my database like:

```
2020-02-22 08:00:00.000
```

And what I would really like is something like this:

```
2020-02-22 08:00
```

I've come across some suggestions for date and some for seconds, not really both, and not just in the model like this so that I don't need to implement extra functions.

Comment: DateTime will always have date and time properties but you can use the formatting via ToString(). [See Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: in addition to the Jawad's comment, this DateTime.Now.ToString("g") should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime is stored as a datetime in your db (which is a very good thing), your ORM layer should convert it to a C# datetime datatype. You can use this code to print it without the seconds:

```
Console.WriteLine("date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm}", 
               theDate);
```

[see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

If your datetime is stored as a string in your db (which is a very bad thing), use this regex will do it:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xudHNo/1)